# How to pinch the captureelement's size in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, grid, scaletransform

Hello I used scaletransform to resize the image, and mediaelement with grid in UWP

So I searched this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform) and then I can resize them.

and now I want to resize the captureelement in Grid control

I used the same method that I applied to the image

But I can't resize grid. How can I do that?

This is part of my code in xaml

```
<Grid Name="Cam_grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.ZIndex="5" ManipulationMode="Scale" Width="420" Height="350"  >
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="Cam1_scale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TextBox Name="Cam_load" Text="Loading..."/>
    <CaptureElement   Name="PreviewControl" Stretch="Fill" ManipulationMode="All" />
    <TextBox Name="Cam_close" Text="Closing..." />
</Grid>
```

And this is my cs code

```
private void Cam_grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dragTranslation_C.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragTranslation_C.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    Cam1_scale.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    Cam1_scale.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
}
```

Is this impossible? I'm really wondering

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't resize grid"? What does the given code instead?

Comment: I mean I used the scaletransform in grid before ,so i can resize the grid's size
but now i can't resize the grid with captureelement (this control brings webcam's preview)
was my explanation unclear?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. The `Grid` contains `CaptureElement` can scale well in a mobile emulator. Please provide more code snippet and the testing environment information.